# Stokes Theorem without compact support

Tags: differential-topology, stokes-theorem

I am looking for a version of Stokes Theorem on manifolds that does not assume compact support of the differential form $\omega$. In fact I have found the following statement in the book Riemannian Geometry And Geometric Analysis by Jost:

Theorem 2.1.6 Let $M$ be an orientable $m$-dimensional differentiable submanifold
of the differentiable manifold $N$ with smooth boundary. That is, $\partial M$ is assumed to
be an $(m-1)$-dimensional differentiable submanifold of $N$, and let $\omega$ be a smooth
$(m-1)$-form on $N$. Then, provided that these integrals exist, for instance if $\overline{M}$ is
compact,

$\int_Md\omega = \int_{\partial M}\omega$.

I am having some doubts about this result, and found something which I believe might be a counterexample.

Choose $N=\mathbb{R}$, $\overline{M}= [0,\infty)$, such that $\partial M = \{0\}$. Let $\omega = f$ be a function which is bounded towards infinity, $f(\infty):=\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)<\infty$. Integrating, we then have

$\int_Md\omega = \int_0^\infty f'dx = f(\infty) - f(0)$, but $\int_{\partial M}\omega = -f(0)$.

This happens because the limit point $\{\infty\}$ is not viewed as a boundary of $\mathbb{R}$. Is this a valid counterexample or did I make some mistake? How could we fix this Theorem to still hold, without assuming compact support?

Comment: I can not find this statement or any statement resembling it in the book. Are you sure you have the reference right? In any case, your example is sound.

Comment: I am referring to Page 60 of the 7th edition. Perhaps the result does not appear in earlier versions of the book.

Comment: Try writing down a explicit example for $f$.

Comment: $f=1$ should work, no? What I am struggeling with is finding an analogous example in 2 dimensions, so maybe the theorem works for $m\geq 2$?

Comment: In your example, $\overline{M}$ has to be understood as $[-\infty,+\infty]$ in order to your statement to be right.